# Using CSS to align two text input elements

Tags: css, stylesheet

Sorry if this is such a basic question, but how do I left align two text box elements in different divs with labels that are different lengths?  I have a screen shot below.  I want to align the textbox for "Dive Profile Id" and "Dive Profile Name".  The way I have it now, is the "Dive Profile Id" and "Description" labels and textbox are in one div and the "Dive Profile Name" is in another div.  How would I align these two input elements?

[image]

Here is my actual HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <LINK href="dive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" >
            <div id="header">
                <form name="header">
                    <div id="topline">
                       <label for="profileId" style="vertical-align: top">Dive Profile Id </label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileId" id="profileId">
                       <label for="descriptionTxtArea" style="vertical-align: top;padding-left: 20px">Description</label><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="descrptionTxtArea" id="descriptionTxtArea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="secondline">
                       <label for="profileName" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; float: left">Dive Profile Name</label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileName" id="profileName">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
                        <div id="profilePlot">
                        </div>

                        <div id="buttonMenu">
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div name="diveData">
        </div>    
        <div id="mydiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I have been researching this.  Maybe I'm just not understanding CSS.

Comment: I guess I could use tables but isn't that pretty "old school".  My understanding is that styles are the better way to lay out elements on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy way is to transform your label into inline blocks and giving them the same size

with something like this :

```
<label class="label" for="profileId"...
<label class="label" for="profileName" ...
```

and the CSS, for example:

```
.label {
   display: inline-box;
   width: 100px;
}
```

so if you want the style in your html :

```
<div id="topline">
   <label for="profileId" style="display:inline-box;width:100px;">Dive Profile Id </label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileId" id="profileId">
   <label for="descriptionTxtArea" style="vertical-align: top;padding-left: 20px">Description</label><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="descrptionTxtArea" id="descriptionTxtArea"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="secondline">
   <label for="profileName" style="display:inline-box;width:100px;">Dive Profile Name</label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileName" id="profileName">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <LINK href="dive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" >
            <div id="header">
                <form name="header">
                    <div id="topline">
                       <label for="profileId" style="vertical-align: top">Dive Profile Id </label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileId" id="profileId">
                        <br />
                       <label for="descriptionTxtArea" style="vertical-align: top;padding-left: 20px; ">Description</label><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="descrptionTxtArea" id="descriptionTxtArea"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="secondline">
                       <label for="profileName" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; float: left">Dive Profile Name</label><input style="vertical-align: top" type="text" name="profileName" id="profileName">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
                        <div id="profilePlot">
                        </div>

                        <div id="buttonMenu">
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div name="diveData">
        </div>    
        <div id="mydiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work.  It basically put all of the input elements in one column...one below the next.  Now none of the input elements are left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap.css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--INCLUDE BOOTSTRAP.CSS--->
        <!-- <LINK href="dive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> -->
<style>
label {
    display: inline!important;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" >
            <div id="header">
                <form name="header">
                    <div id="topline" class="span8 control-group">
                       <label for="profileId" class="control-label">Dive Profile Id </label>
                       <input  type="text" name="profileId" id="profileId" class="controls">
                       <label for="descriptionTxtArea" class="control-label">Description</label>
                       <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="descrptionTxtArea" id="descriptionTxtArea" class="controls"></textarea>
                    </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div id="secondline " class="control-group">
                       <label for="profileName" class="control-label" >Dive Profile Name</label>
                       <input  type="text" name="profileName" id="profileName" class="controls">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
                        <div id="profilePlot">
                        </div>

                        <div id="buttonMenu">
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div name="diveData">
        </div>    
        <div id="mydiv">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```